# How can I create a map from object properties?

Tags: groovy

I get an object via some 3rd party api. I use a wrapper function to get it and then return a map from its properties:

```
wrapperFunc() {
    def myObj = someapi.getblah().getSomeObect()
    return [
        aaa: myObj.aaa,
        bbb: myObj.bbb,
        ccc: myObj.ccc
    ]
}
```

Now I could manually go through EVERY property in the object like this, but is there an elegant groovy feature to dynamically build a map from the object's properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
class Widget {
    int width
    int height

    static void main(args) {
        def obj = new Widget(width: 7, height: 9)

        List<MetaProperty> metaProperties = obj.metaClass.properties

        def props = [:]
        for(MetaProperty mp : metaProperties) {
            props[mp.name] = mp.getProperty(obj)
        }

        // props will look like [width:7, class:class demo.Widget, height:9]
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me, maybe i dont understand. When i run that and do props.oneOfMyProps it is null

Comment: I don't understand why that would be unless the property really does have a `null` value.  Sorry I can't help.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a variant of @jeff-scott-brown's answer.

First, create a class that contains the Object-to-Map logic that uses the Groovy `MetaClass` to access a type's properties. `findAll` filters out the "class" property, which I assume you don't care about. The `collectEntries` line transforms each `MetaProperty` object into a Map entry.

```
class ElegantGroovyFeature {
    static Map asType(Object o, Class m) {
        if (m == Map) {
            o.metaClass.properties
                       .findAll { it.getSetter() != null }
                       .collectEntries { prop -> [prop.name, prop.getProperty(o)] }        
        } else {
            o.asType(m)
        }
    }   
}
```

The extension class overrides the `asType` method, which corresponds to the `as` operator, enabling you to convert arbitrary objects to Maps using `obj as Map` expressions:

```
def obj = someapi.getBlah().getSomeObject()
use (ElegantGroovyFeature) {
    def mapOfProperties = obj as Map
}
```

Answer (score -1):

const obj = { foo: 'bar', baz: 42 }; 
const map = new Map(Object.entries(obj));
console.log(map); // Map { foo: "bar", ba`enter code here`z: 42 }

Comment: `const map = new Map(Object.entries(obj));` - That doesn't look like Groovy code.  That looks like Javascript.